# Hololens2 does not recognize hands

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

When developing the Hololens2 application with unity, I imported the MRTK base package plugin.
Debug in unity, call hand part, can interact normally.

When I opened the program in Hololen2, I had no problems with other functions such as vision and network.
The only problem was that my hand could not be recognized properly.

I tried to change some configuration of MRTK, but it didn't work
Then in order to reduce error range, I in Hololens2 development deployed MRKT example scene Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/HandTracking/Scenes
But there are still problems. So I think the error is in "Player Settings".

I looked up the information and mainly set up "XR Plug-in Management".

[image: XR Plug-in Management Window]

[image: Windows Mixed Reality Window]

I also set up “Player->Publishing Settings->Capabilities”，tick "InternetClient, Webcam, Microphone, SpatialPerception,GazeInput".
tick"Holographic"in“Player->Publishing Settings->Supported Device Families ”

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the previous development, these Settings were applied. There is no such thing as unrecognition of the hand.

Am I missing any key Settings? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide your Unity version, Visual Studio version and MRTK version? Which official sample did you use for testing? How do you tell if the hand is not recognized? Can you use gestures? Can you interact near/far by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided it's important to note that hand tracking is dependent on several factors such as lighting conditions, hand positioning, and the angle of the hand with respect to the Hololens2 camera. Therefore, it's possible that the hand tracking issue you are facing may not necessarily be due to a misconfiguration of the MRTK.
That said, there are some key settings and configurations that you can check to ensure that hand tracking is properly set up in your Hololens2 application. Here are some suggestions:
Ensure that the MRTK is properly configured: In particular, pay attention to the input configuration settings and ensure that hand tracking is enabled.
Check the hand mesh: Hand tracking relies on the Hololens2's ability to recognize the shape and position of the user's hands. It's possible that the hand mesh is not being properly recognized by the Hololens2. Check the hand mesh settings in your application to ensure that it's properly configured.
As mentioned earlier, hand tracking can be affected by lighting conditions. Try testing your application in different lighting conditions to see if the issue persists.
Hand tracking may not work properly if the user's hands are too close or too far away from the Hololens2 camera. Ensure that the user is holding their hands at an appropriate distance and angle from the camera.
Use the latest version of the MRTK. As newer versions may include bug fixes and optimizations that could improve hand tracking performance.